# RxJava: Continue next iteration even if error occurs

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-binding

I'm using `RxSearchView` to emit out the results of a search query from an API to a recyclerview. However, if one of those query fails, `onError()` is called(which is expected) but the subscription as a whole is also canceled. Subsequent queries are not executed at all.

How should i modify the code so that the call to `onError()` is prevented when a query fails and the next incoming queries are executed normally?

Here's a code snippet:

```
subscription = RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
                .debounce(500, MILLISECONDS)
                .filter(charSequence -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence))
                .map(CharSequence::toString)
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .switchMap(query -> apiService.getSearchResults(query))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<SearchResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SearchResponse searchResponse) {
                        if (searchResponse.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
                            //update Adapter
                        } else {
                            //update error views
                        }
                    }

                });
```

P.S: I am using `switchMap()` so that the results of old queries are ignored, if the results of new query has arrived.

Comment: You just need to wire the necessary error handling logic (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators) to the apiService.getSearchResults(query) call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle this error and return an object instead. You can do it, for example, by using [onErrorResumeNext](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onErrorResumeNext(rx.functions.Func1)) operator with `apiService.getSearchResults(query)` call. What you are going to return - depends on you, you can even return `null` if you want, but better to create some wrapper which can carry both response status flag and normal response if received.

Something like:

```
subscription = RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
            .debounce(500, MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(charSequence -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence))
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .switchMap(query -> apiService
                                   .getSearchResults(query)
                                   .onErrorResumeNext(error -> null)
            )
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<SearchResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(SearchResponse searchResponse) {
                    if (searchResponse != null && searchResponse.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
                        //update Adapter
                    } else {
                        //update error views
                    }
                }

            });
```

Of course, this is naive example with using null, in reality you need to write error handling logic. Better to return wrapper, because if using `RxJava 2`, then it doesn't support `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, what if i return null and check for null SearchResponse in onNext? Would that be a correct approach?

Comment: it should. But keep in mind, that if you migrate to RxJava 2, then you can have different behavior - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls

Comment: I would suggest that you use `.onErrorResumeNext(error -> Observable.empty())`, this way you won't need null checks.